# How can I separate gear oil from metal shavings to weigh worn metal?

Tags: gears, fluid-filtration

I have tested a gear box for many hours. Where the gears are made of a hardened steel alloy and the housing is 7000 series aluminum. Now I drained the gear box of its gear oil and I need to weight the metal shavings in that oil. So I can put in fresh oil and test the gear box for a couple more hours. And then do the test all over again. Can anyone give me a good idea as to how I can accurately separate the oil with out losing the tiny pieces of metal? I thought I could filter the oil through coffee filters then give it a thorough cleaning with hot water and soap, then drying it in the oven. Can anyone tell me if this is a good idea or can you come up with a better one?

Comment: If the gears are made of steel, the usual solution would be to run the oil over a small magnet.

Comment: The problem is that half the metal is aluminum. I will update my post. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: You could use a centrifuge, but I would think that your solution would work as well and would be cheaper (unless you already have a centrifuge at hand).

Comment: Yea I don't have access to one. Thank You

Comment: If only the *housing* is aluminum, what is removing the metal from it? Do you *know* that "half the metal" in the oil is aluminum, or is that just a guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Standard lab approach is vacuum filtration](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chemlab/techniques/vfiltration.html): Get a Buchner funnel and filter paper sized to capture the smallest particles you care to measure.  Now:

1. Weigh filter.
2. Place filter in funnel and wet with solvent.
3. Connect funnel to vacuum filter flask.
4. Turn on vacuum.
5. Pour sample into funnel.
6. Continue to rinse sample with a volatile solvent until it is clean.  For rinsing off oil you could use acetone.
7. Wait a few moments for solvent to evaporate.
8. Weigh filter with sample.

Comment: Only problem is that I do not have access to that equipment. But I will find out if I can use the chem lab at my university. Thank You

Comment: @Chris: Not expensive stuff.  You can get a funnel, flask, and filters for a few tens of dollars.  If you're patient enough (and the oil isn't too viscous) you don't even need the vacuum; you can just wait for it to drain through the filter on its own.  For vacuum you might already have a hand vacuum pump (e.g., for bleeding brakes) in your shop, or you can [assemble a water-powered aspirator like this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/45212/5354).

Comment: I needed it done asap. So here is what I did, and tell me if you can help me solve this. I went and bought some coffee filters and ran the solution through the coffee filter. The solution is a mixture of Aluminum and Steal alloys, Purple Power Degreaser and water. I left the solution to filter for about an hour then I put the filter and the residue into the oven at 215F to left the water and some of the oil to evaporate. Now I am left over with metal and this gray powder and some of it is still in a sludge form. What do you suggest I can do to accurately weight the metal

Comment: [Here is a picture of the residue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5j_BdtRjSyAQi1BWGZxWjZFMW8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Chris: Assuming you didn't weigh that particular filter first, I guess I would first weigh a bunch of filters and hope their weight variation is within your desired margin of error, so you can subtract the filter weight.  If there's still "sludge" then there is still liquid, so I would try to rinse that out with acetone (or another handy volatile grease solvent) until you're left only with powder once the cleaner evaporates.  Once you're dealing with sludge this rinse can require some mechanical agitation to get the solvent to break things up without running a continuous rinse process.

Comment: @Chris - Another thought, if you don't need to be *too* precise, is that you could burn what's left and weigh it.  To account for the filter ash, burn a plain filter and weigh its ash.  At low enough temperature hopefully you won't add to the mass of the metal alloys through oxidization, and by now you will have reduced the oil and degreaser mass in your sample enough that their solid combustion products will fall within your desired margin of error.

Comment: I would mix a *liberal* quantity of solvent with the oil before hitting the filter.